# Getting Feed data from Facebook API in a date range

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

I need to get all the entries in the user's feed after a day and before another day. Since I don't know how many entries there are in that period and the parameter `LIMIT` seems to be mandatory, I set limit to, for example, 100.

When the data is ready to be parsed I have to check (or don't I?) if the key `PAGING` is in the result set and, if so, query again with the data stored in it.

I am not sure if this logic is correct. My first idea was to loop the result set while PAGING is still there and then query again. If PAGING is empty, return the JSON to the user. That would mean that there is no more pages in my query and I got all the data I needed.

I am using the SINCE and UNTIL parameters to specify the date range.

The problem is that I always get an error of time limit exceeded: **Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in...**

It seems that `PAGING` is always there, so my loop is actually searching for all the entries in the user's feed since he or she created his or her account. I'm not sure about this, but one thing I am sure: it is performing like 13, 14 or 15 queries befire timing out. And as I could see, some of the results are not in the date range as specified (I think it's because the key PAGING doesn't have all the parameters initially set).

Do you know guys if this is the best solution to query for the data in the user's feed?

One more thing: I am testing with my own feed. Some results I don't recognize as something I posted in my timeline. So I'm assuming they are comments and not posts/status. Do you know anything about this?

@EDIT1

Take a look at this:

My first query:
/me/feed?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&fields=message&since=2014-02-11&until=2014-02-17&limit=100

The string in PAGING->NEXT
https://graph.facebook.com/MY_ID/feed?fields=message&limit=100&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&until=1392153316

It cut off the `since` parameter and I think `until` was converted to UNIX time (since 1970).

But I checked in my timeline and everything I posted in it from 11/02/2014 to 17/02/2014 is in the result set (including some things some friends shared with me and some things I have no idea what they are).

So how do I know when I have to use the PAGING->NEXT to get more data I really need??

I will try to edit this with some code in a minute

Answer (score 10):

You have to use unix timestamps for the since and until parameters, otherwise it shouldn't work.

```
/me/feed?since=1391244171&until=1391848971&fields=message
```